# "Why does it output 100?"

Tags: c, for-loop, output

```
for(x=0; x<100; x++);
 printf(“%d”,x);
```

why it gives 100

(i) Identify bug/bugs in this program segment
(ii) Write a correct version of this program segment

I tried

```
for(x=0; x<100; x++){
 printf(“%d”,x);}
```

ı can see all numbers 0 to 100 but

```
for(x=0; x<100; x++);
 printf(“%d”,x);
```

ı can see only 100 why ? ı dont know the reason

Comment: Did you notice the extra semi-colon?

Comment: empty for loop/ loop without body. The last value of x was 100 and  thus you see only 100.

Comment: It sounds like you already identified and removed the errant semi-colon...

Comment: Turn all warnings on, and it would have flagged this.

Comment: If instead, you had defined `x` at the scope where it is needed, with `for(int x=0; x<100; x++)` the compiler would have told you the error.

Answer (score 2):

> I can see only 100 why? I dont know the reason

Because a semi-colon terminates a statement.

To better understand what's happening, format your code properly.  (Better yet, use an IDE which formats the code for you.  And ***do not use a word processor as an IDE***.  Those fancy quotes in your code are syntax errors.)  The original code is this:

```
for(x=0; x<100; x++);
printf("%d",x);
```

Two statements, unrelated to one another.  The first one is a loop, by itself, with no loop body.  It repeats, successfully doing nothing 100 times.  The second statement outputs a value.  Compare that to your corrected code:

```
for(x=0; x<100; x++) {
  printf("%d",x);
}
```

Now what you have is a loop, the body of which contains one statement.  That statement is executed 100 times, each time outputting a value.

Consistently and meaningfully formatting your code for readability is not there to help the compiler.  It's there to help you.  Keep your code human-readable and you, as a human, will be better able to read and understand it.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(x=0; x<100; x++); printf(“%d”,x);
```

There is a semicolon between the for loop and the print. So the print is not in the loop.

`x` will be counted from 0 to 100. After the empty loop completes, it will print the last value (100).